# JQuery Select Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery.

I have a list of radio buttons which I am getting this way:

```
var $selectAllRadios = $('input:radio[value=select]');
```

Now in this list I want to be able to select all the radio buttons which are currently checked and also the number of radio buttons that are currently checked.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector to grab the selected radio buttons, and the [`length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property to find out how many there are.

```
var $checkedRadios = $('input:radio[value=select]:checked');
var count = $checkedRadios.length;
```

Comment: Hi Jon,what if I want the count of no of radiobuttons which are not checked ??

Comment: @Siddharth: Now *that* is a very trivial question. There's enough information in this page to figure that out.

Answer (score 2):

This is a duplicated, you should search the site before asking a question:

[Radio button selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353290/radio-button-selected)

[How to know if radio is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666934/how-to-know-if-radio-is-checked)

As for the number of elements you can always use the length property.

Answer (score 2):

Use this to get the `length` of the radio buttons that are checked.

```
$('input:radio[value=select]').filter(':checked').length
```

To get the `length` of radio butons that are not checked.

```
$('input:radio[value=select]').filter(':not(:checked)').length
```